# One vs Two tables (database design)

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a database for a Go/Baduk association. This association organizes regular Go tournaments. Participants in these tournaments may or may not be members of the association.

My first **approach (A)** was to create two tables: *Person* and *Member*. For each *Person* I only need the fields *Name*, *Email* and *Nationality*. A *Member* would then be a *Person* with extra fields. Primary Key for *Member* would be a foreign key from *Person*. This is a one to one relationship - which I know should be avoided.

I then thought a better **approach (B)** could be a single table, *Person*, with a boolean field called something like *IsMember*, and the extra fields are only necessary/mandatory if *IsMember* is true.

What are your thoughts on this? Which approach (A or B) is the correct one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both have their uses. The "best" option depends on your data distribution between the two types.

Comment: BTW, these aproaches have names. A is called class table inheritance.  B is called single table inheritance.  These are useful buzzwords for web searches.

Comment: Most participants in tournaments will be members. For ten participants, there are usually 1 to 3 players who are not members. The Association itself is small. Right now there are 18 members and I can't see it grow past 3 times that value in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below input you can come to a decision.

Approach A

You avoid unwanted data on the first table and the second table will not have any null value for the extra columns. This will save a bit of space if your application grows. Which will also help in performance.
When you come to your application you will have to run an extra query to the second table to check whether the person is a member. 
If you think about having a IsMember column in your person table you can avoid the second query if the person is not a member.

Approach B

You put all the data in the same place. Here you will have either null or spaces (Preferred) in the table.You will have the column to determine whether the person is a member. 
when it comes to your application you will only have to query once to get the person.
Lets say most people in your system are not members then this approach will be bad as you will be storing more nulls.

As per the comment by Joel the final approach should depend on your data.

Comment: Why do you say spaces are "preferred" in Approach B?  I think NULL is more appropriate, since a space is a value and NULL, by definition, means "no value here", and if a person is not a member then the member-only fields will have no value.

Comment: Thank you. I've replied Joel about the data distribution. Today I'm leaning toward Approach A, and I think I'll use the IsMember column, as you suggested.

Comment: @Brian space will be much easier when it comes to coding level but true null is better at database level

Comment: I've never had trouble handling NULL values in my code, but... [shrug] your mileage may vary.